# Change attribute value prefixed by a namespace using simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I would like to change the value of an attribute prefixed by a namespace using simplexml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16">
```

These methods are not working:

```
$usesSDKTag['android:minSdkVersion'] = $minSdkVersion;
$usesSDKTag['minSdkVersion'] = $minSdkVersion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating the node and adding attributes with namespace prefix to it:

```
if( isset($xmlManifest->{"uses-sdk"}) ) {
     unset($xmlManifest->{"uses-sdk"});
}
$usesSDKTag = $xmlManifest->addChild('uses-sdk');
$usesSDKTag->addAttribute('android:minSdkVersion', $minSdkVersion, 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android');
$usesSDKTag->addAttribute('android:targetSdkVersion', $minSdkVersion, 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android');
$usesSDKTag->addAttribute('android:maxSdkVersion', $maxSdkVersion, 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android');
```